# Creating website links with JSON info using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing, amazon-s3

I currently have a website hosted on AWS. My static pages are in a public S3 bucket, and in the same bucket is a JSON file containing the names and URLs of files I would like to display on my webpage. Heres an example of what the JSON looks like:

```
{
  "bass": [{
      "bass-song1": "http://www.website.com/bass-song1.pdf"
    }, {
      "bass-song2": "http://www.website.com/bass-song2.pdf"
    }],
  "drum": [{
      "drum-song1": "http://www.website.com/drum-song1.pdf"
    }, {
      "drum-song2": "http://www.website.com/drum-song2.pdf"
    }],
  "guitar": [{
      "guitar-song1": "http://www.website.com/guitar-song1.pdf"
    }, {
      "guitar-song2": "http://www.website.com/guitar-song2.pdf"
    }]
}
```

As you can see, the musical instrument (bass, drum, guitar) is the key, and its associated value is a list that contains a few songs in this format: {"song title": "URL of the file"}.

**MY GOAL: I want to write a javascript that parses this JSON file, creating links to these PDF files using their name (e.g. "bass-song1") as the link's title, and its associated URL (e.g. http://www.website.com/bass-song1.pdf).** Heres what I have so far (this is in the body of my HTML page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

async function getData(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  return response.json()
}

async function main() {
  const data = await getData(<URL OF THE JSON IN MY S3 BUCKET>);

  // 'instrument' example: 'bass'
  for (var instrument in data) {
    // store the list of bass songs
    var song_list = data[instrument]

    // for each song (list element),
    for (var song in song_list) {
      // store the song's object in 'song_object' (python dict = js object)
      var song_object = song_list[song]
      // create a link with the name and URL of the PDF song file
      var link_str = song_object.constructor.name;
      var link_url = song_object[link_str];

      // TO DO: CREATE LINK TO APPEAR ON WEBSITE

    }
  }
}
// Run main; didn't work without doing this
main();

</script>
```

I would greatly appreciate any pointers or advice. I'm trying to learn javascript with this project, and I must've spent 7-8 hours today trying to figure this out (along with associated tasks). I know Python and HTML, but I am brand new to Javascript.

Thank you,
Sebastian

Comment: Step one is to definitely put your JS code in a file and loading that file using `<script src=...></script>` instead of inlining it. Also, don't use `for/in` with anything that isn't a plain object (not with arrays, not with classed/prototyped instances/etc). In this case, you want `song_list.forEach(song => ...)`.

Comment: consider using javascript frameworks such as `React` at least `Jquery`. writing plain javascript is time-consuming.

Comment: Don't inline a <1kB script, waste a whole separate HTTP call getting it? Use jQuery when vanilla JS is feature-packed in 2020? Weird comment section. (Also, that is a named object, they _would_ want at least one `for/in`. I think their code is a good start.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.constructor.name` prints the name of the object constructor - your `for x in data` call would iterate over the keys of that object, which are all Strings - basically, `Object.constructor.name` would print "String" and you would actually just want the iterator value itself there.

Here's a revised version of the code that uses `document.createElement` and `document.body.append` to create a new DOM element and add it to the page respectively. And don't worry, you can inline it if you want buddy. Inline your heart out.

You can use `append` on any DOMNode, i.e., `document.getElementById("myContainer").append(myNewLink)`.

```js
async function getData(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  return response.json()
}

var testOb = {
  "bass": [{
      "bass-song1": "http://www.website.com/bass-song1.pdf"
    }, {
      "bass-song2": "http://www.website.com/bass-song2.pdf"
    }],
  "drum": [{
      "drum-song1": "http://www.website.com/drum-song1.pdf"
    }, {
      "drum-song2": "http://www.website.com/drum-song2.pdf"
    }],
  "guitar": [{
      "guitar-song1": "http://www.website.com/guitar-song1.pdf"
    }, {
      "guitar-song2": "http://www.website.com/guitar-song2.pdf"
    }]
};


async function main(data) {
  // this will contain your data object
  // const data = await getData(<URL OF THE JSON IN MY S3 BUCKET>);

  for (var instrument in data) {
    // 'instrument' example: 'bass'

    // song list
    var songs = data[instrument];
    songs.forEach(function(song){

      // 'song' example: {guitar-song1: "http://www.website.com/guitar-song1.pdf"}
      for (var songName in song) {
        var songUrl = song[songName];
        
        // create element in DOM
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        var lineBreak = document.createElement("br");
        
        a.setAttribute("href", songUrl);
        a.innerHTML = songName;

        // append to body
        document.body.append(a);
        document.body.append(lineBreak);

      }
    });

  }
}

main(testOb);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Christian and @Alex!! This worked well, I just had to add some formatting (line breaks, headers for each section, and change the background color of the links to make them stand out).

Answer (score 2):

You made a very good start you have objects within your object so the for in loop within the for in loop is a good approach.

You can simplify your inner loop as you have the “name” (key) already from the loop.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

async function getData(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  return response.json()
}

async function main() {
  const data = await getData(<URL OF THE JSON IN MY S3 BUCKET>);

  // 'instrument' example: 'bass'
  for (var instrument in data) {
    // store the list of bass songs
    var song_list = data[instrument]

    // for each song (list element),
    for (var song_object of song_list){

      for (var song_name in song_object) {

        // create a link with the name and URL of the PDF song file
        var link_str = song_name;
        var link_url = song_object[song_name];

        // TO DO: CREATE LINK TO APPEAR ON WEBSITE
        const a = document.createElement(‘a’);
        a.href = link_url;
        a.innerText = link_str;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
     }
    }
  }
}
// Run main; didn't work without doing this
main();

</script>
```

Comment: Oh, bigtime jynx, almost the same exact code and just 30 seconds apart. Agreed that OP was off to a great start!